# How to use DialoGpt with DJL

Tags: python, java, deep-learning, djl

I need the use pre-trained model of DialoGpt but with Java. Could you provide me a code sample. It's not necessary to use only DJL, you can use every Java-written library.

I've tried to copy Python code to Java according to the code sample at the end of the page: https://huggingface.co/microsoft/DialoGPT-large
but I don't know what to start with.

Here's the code (you can also find it at the end of the link above):

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch


tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-large")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-large")

# Let's chat for 5 lines
for step in range(5):
    # encode the new user input, add the eos_token and return a tensor in Pytorch
    new_user_input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input(">> User:") + tokenizer.eos_token, return_tensors='pt')

    # append the new user input tokens to the chat history
    bot_input_ids = torch.cat([chat_history_ids, new_user_input_ids], dim=-1) if step > 0 else new_user_input_ids

    # generated a response while limiting the total chat history to 1000 tokens, 
    chat_history_ids = model.generate(bot_input_ids, max_length=1000, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)

    # pretty print last ouput tokens from bot
    print("DialoGPT: {}".format(tokenizer.decode(chat_history_ids[:, bot_input_ids.shape[-1]:][0], skip_special_tokens=True)))
```